# How to get python to search for whole numbers in a string-not just digits

Tags: python

Okay please do not close this and send me to a similar question because I have been looking for hours at similar questions with no luck.

Python can search for digits using re.search([0-9])

However, I want to search for any whole number. It could be 547 or 2 or 16589425. I don't know how many digits there are going to be in each whole number.

Furthermore I need it to specifically find and match numbers that are going to take a form similar to this: 1005.2.15 or 100.25.1 or 5.5.72 or 1102.170.24 etc.

It may be that there isn't a way to do this using re.search but any info on what identifier I could use would be amazing.

Comment: Are you looking for whole numbers in the string, or for IP addresses? Different parts of your question seem to be looking for different things.

Comment: So would that match as 1005, 2, 15, 100, 25, 1, etc.? Or would those be eliminated because they have periods inside? You need to be explicit about what you are looking for. In your case, probably just 1 or more digits (`[0-9]+`), using a greedy search.

Comment: You _can_ do what you're describing with a regular expression, but you need to be more specific about what you want to match.

Comment: The regex `\d+` will match one more more consecutive digits, i.e 1 or 345 or 238723.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
import re

your_string = 'this is 125.156.56.531 and this is 0540505050.5 !'
result = re.findall(r'\d[\d\.]*', your_string)
print(result)
```

output

```
['125.156.56.531', '0540505050.5']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're looking for whole numbers only, try `re.search(r"[0-9]+")`

Comment: Plus would only search for 0-1 instances of the `[0-9]` group. OP wants any length to be matched.

Comment: + matches one or more. ? Is the optional modifier

Comment: @Ranga Yes. Thank you. Fixed.

Comment: @hmm Now that I've corrected my answer, please consider removing your down vote. As an occasional contributor, each down vote makes a large impact on my rep.